# Devise is saving user with empty UID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

Running the statement below, expected to save the user with the same email and UID: `email == uid`:

### Current behavior

```
user = User.create(email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: '1' * 8, password_confirmation: '1' * 8)
user.email # 'myemail@gmail.com'
user.uid # nil
```

### Excepted Behavior

```rb
user = User.create(email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: '1' * 8, password_confirmation: '1' * 8)
user.email # 'myemail@gmail.com'
user.uid # 'myemail@gmail.com'
```

What's wrong with my User model? I remember that, when I created a new user, the devise automatically fill the user's uid with the email.
I have been pasted the User model code below to help track any kind weird code.

### Environment

- Ruby **2.4.1**
- Rails **5.2.3**
- Devise **4.7.1**

### User model

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord # :nodoc:
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation

  self.table_name = 'users'

  include Status

  enum role: Role.to_enum

  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :company_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :timeoutable

  belongs_to :person, class_name: 'Pessoa'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person

  belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Empresa'
  has_many :permissions,
           class_name: 'UserPermission',
           dependent: :delete_all,
           foreign_key: 'user_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions
  validates_associated :permissions

  before_validation :load_predefined_permissions

  # validations
  validates :permissions, presence: true, if: -> { role.to_s == 'custom' }
  validates_presence_of :role, :person

  def timeout_in
    15.minutes
  end

  def active_for_authentication?
    super && account_active?
  end

  def account_active?
    manager? || (ativo? && permissions.count.positive?)
  end

  def skip_password_validation?
    ['true', true, 1, '1'].include?(skip_password_validation)
  end

  def permission?(subject_class, action)
    permissions.any? { |permission| permission.subject_class == subject_class && permission.action == action }
  end

  def cached_permissions
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key_with_version}/permissions") do
      permissions
    end
  end

  def clear_cached_data
    Rails.cache.delete("#{cache_key_with_version}/permissions")
  end

  protected

  def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation?

    super
  end

  private

  def load_predefined_permissions
    return if role.to_s == 'custom' || manager? || (!role_changed? && !permissions.empty?)

    self.permissions = UserPermission.initialize_by_user(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it including the `DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User` concern at the `User` model.
¯_(⊙︿⊙)_/¯

[answer to reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2688#issuecomment-243728805)